# Submit model attribute with nested objects in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc form that has a model attribute. This model has a nested object inside of it called Address. When I submit the form, all the non-nested fields are populated in the model fine, but I get a type mismatch error for the Address.

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.sample.types.Address' for property 'address': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

The controller that populates the view with the form is putting a person object in the MV, here is the form in the JSP:

```
<form:form id="formId"
           method="POST"
           action="/submit"
           modelAttribute="person">

    <form:hidden path="name"/>
    <form:hidden path="age" />
    <form:hidden path="address"/>

</form:form>
```

I can see on the page with the form, that the from tag gets converted to this:

```
<input id="address" name="address" type="hidden" value="Address(line1=123 fake street, line2=null, line3=null, city=null, state=null, country=null, postalCode=null, addressId=123456)"/>
```

From the error I get the hint that I probably need to define something that tells Spring how to convert this string to the Address object. Is that right or is something else wrong? Where can I find documentation on how to do this?

**EDIT** it looks like Spring formatters is what I am looking for: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-define-formatter.html , however it seems like there are multiple ways to do this. Converter vs Formatter vs PropertyEditor. Does anyone know which is the correct one for this?

Comment: Nope. You need an input for each property of address: `<form:hidden path="address.line1"/>`, `<form:hidden path="address.line2"/>` etc.

Comment: I was able to get what I wanted working through a formatter, but I don't know if I want to keep it. Basically the formatter returns the value as a JSON string to the UI and then the parse method in the formatter converts it back. I am trying to see what are the downsides to this.